# Django Rest Framework - Model relationships with nested foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to replicate the data scheme for the data seen [here](https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch/1385). Each launch has a location with a **single** pad, my model is currently defined as shown below:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Location'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Locations'


class Pad(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
    info_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    wiki_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    map_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="pads", blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Pad'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Pads'
```

If I query the launch from a Django shell it or if I serialize ([seen here](https://github.com/ItsCalebJones/SpaceLaunchNow-Server/blob/655f49302025e3eaea645111038123ad393f2ec6/api/v201/serializers.py)) the launch with Django Restframework it pulls **all pads** possible for a location instead of the **single** pad that the launch is assigned to.

Example:

```
"location": {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "Cape Canaveral, FL, USA",
    "country_code": "USA",
    "pads": [
        {
            "id": 62,
            "name": "Space Launch Complex 37B, Cape Canaveral, FL",
            "info_url": null,
            "wiki_url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Air_Force_Station_Space_Launch_Complex_37",
            "map_url": "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=28.531700,-80.564950"
        },
        {
            "id": 84,
            "name": "Space Launch Complex 40, Cape Canaveral, FL",
            "info_url": "",
            "wiki_url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Air_Force_Station_Space_Launch_Complex_40",
            "map_url": "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=28.56194122,-80.57735736"
        }
    ]
```

How do I get the relationships to correctly ONLY show the one pad that is assigned to a launch instead of returning all possible pads for a location so that my implementation matches the original functionality as shown in the first link?

EDIT:

Ok so the data is now in the database in the correct format as shown in the shell, a launch has a single pad from a location. The remaining problem is how to serialize it to return exactly like the original data source, with is launch->location->single-pad:

```
>>> launch = Launch.objects.first()
>>> launch
<Launch: Falcon Heavy | STP-2>
>>> launch.pad
<Pad: Launch Complex 39A, Kennedy Space Center, FL>
>>> launch.pad.location
<Location: Kennedy Space Center, FL, USA>
>>> launch.pad.location.pad.all()
<QuerySet [<Pad: Launch Complex 39A, Kennedy Space Center, FL>, <Pad: Launch Complex 39B, Kennedy Space Center, FL>]>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I updated the post to clarify the specific question.

Comment: if you want each location just have one pad, please use OneToOne relation or use ForeignKey relation in location not pad.

Comment: I can't use OneToOne as the datasource can have the following:

    Launch -> Location.id 1 -> Pad.id 1
    Launch -> Location.id 1 -> Pad.id 2

Basically there are multiple pads at each location but a launch will only use one pad. When adding launches to the original data source you set it by the pad id. Maybe thats where i'm messed up... the launch needs to have a foreign key to the pad but then somehow serialize the entire location object with the pad.